# Приложения остановлено из-за исключения

Tags: qt, c++

```
class A {

  QRegExp * r;
public:
  A():r(new QRegExp) { ... }
  ~A() { delete r; }
  ...
  A(const A & a)
  {
     *this = a;
  }

  A & operator=(const A & a)
  {
     if (this == &a)
         return *this;
     delete r; //остановка здесь
     r = new QRegExp();
     return *this;
   }
}

//main
A a;
A a1 = a;
```

Почему и как можно исправить?

Comment: Хм. Вроде всё нормально в коде. Попробуйте пройтись отладчиком. Или сделайте `cout` в начале каждого метода класса `A`.

---
А какое именно исключение?

Comment: @VladD c:\work\build\qt5_workdir\w\s\qtbase\src\corelib\tools\qregexp.cpp:3891: ошибка: Exception at 0x7770af26, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)
Прохожу отладчиком: вызов конструктора копирования -> вызов оператора -> проверка на равенство (false) -> остановка

Comment: @andrey3: О, отлично. А чему равны значения всех релевантных переменных в этой точке? `this`, `a`, `this->r`?

Проверьте на всякий случай, действительно ли из конструктора копирования вызывается оператор присваивания (протрассируйте или добавьте отладочную печать).

Comment: @VladD a = 0x17d3b0 this = 0x17d3a0. значения this-r отладчик не выводит.

Comment: Два раза деструктор вызывается. После первого вызова память по адресу r очищается, а во втором объекте остается "висящий указатель"

Comment: @AlekseyOk вроде бы что-то понимаю, но не понимаю, как поменять код

Comment: @andrey3: А как с трассированием? Вызывается ли `operator=`?

Comment: Да не вызовется он. Объект а1 не создан - вызов конструктора копирования.

Comment: @AlekseyOk: Почему? А из конструктора `A(const A & a)` в строчке `*this = a;`? Аргументируйте.

Comment: @VladD да, конструктор вызывает оператор.

Comment: Моя ошибка. Обнулите r перед вызовом this =a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А, я понял.

Когда вызывается конструктор `A():r(new QRegExp) { ... }`, поле `r` инициализируется. Но когда вызывается конструктор `A(const A & a)`, поле `r` НЕ инициализируется, то есть, имеет случайное значение. Поэтому в операторе присваивания строка `delete r` удаляет случайный объект, «на кого бог пошлёт»!

Простейший выход — переписать конструктор так:

```
A(const A & a) : r(nullptr)
{
    *this = a;
}
```

---

Кстати, у вас не вполне правильно реализовано копирование: вы не копируете `r`, а создаёте новый. Нужно так:

```
 A& operator=(const A& a)
 {
     if (this != &a)
     {
         delete r;
         r = new QRegExp(*(a.r)); // создаёт копию
     }
     return *this;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что код

```
r = a.r;
```

был бы неправильным, т. к. *оба* объекта ссылались бы на один и тот же regex, и в деструкторе было бы непонятно, кому из них надо этот regex удалять.

Answer (score 1):

Если я все верно понял, то вам нужно выделить код из вашего конструктора в отдельный метод.
Конструктор копирования переписать примерно так(код не проверяю):

```
A(const A & a)
{
     this->r = new QRegExp(*(a.r));
     //вызов общего метода
}
```

При необходимости добавить в QRegExp конструктор копирования.
И при необхоимости вызывать выделеный метод в операторе присвоения.

UPD: поправил код.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае будет вызван конструктор копирования.

П.с. реализован он неверно

Comment: @andrey3 а как верно?

Comment: Оопс, ошибочка вышла:
r = new QRegExp(а);

Comment: @AlekseyOk хм... действительно. А как же тогда записать конструктор копирования через оператор присваивая? Просто у меня много раз будут повторяться одни действия и так в нескольких классах подряд.

Comment: @andrey3,
A a1;
a1 = a;

Comment: Или я не верно понял вопрос и тогда вам подойдет, A a1(a);

Comment: @nanotexnik в этом случаи вызывается только оператор присваивания, а конструктор не. И да. Исключения не возникает. Как написать через конструктор, но через оператор, чтобы избежать копирования кода?

Comment: поясните подробнее, я не могу понять что вы хотите. Если вы вызовите через оператор, ты вызов будет через опретор. Если через конструктор, то через конструктор. Это как нарисовать красные линии зелеными фламастерами ?

Comment: проще напишите что вы хотите получить в итогу, и если я пойму, то подскажу

Comment: @nanotexnik если записать через A a1(a);, то также возникает такое исключения. Я хочу избежать копирования кода. В операторе написать копирования всех данных, а в конструкторе пользоваться этим оператором.